# Перестали работать елементы после JQMIGRATE Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Всем привет. Недавно на сайте перестали работать некоторые элементы - вот этот переключатель и гамбургер меню.
В консольке вылезло сообщение `JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1`
Перепробовал кучу способов, плагин Dequeue jQuery Migrate, wp_register_script и вот такое http://prntscr.com/h2xq98 . Но результата 0. Ничего не помогает.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь. Вот сайт - http://antin204.beget.tech/

Comment: Пожалуйста, поместите код не картинкой, а текстом. Он должен индексироваться.

Comment: с jQuery migrate бороться не надо - проблема 100% в другом. Сообщение "Migrate is installed" есть на всех сайтах WordPress, это нормально.